# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'prevdeps.length')

Tags: react-native

Can anybody help me with this error. «undefined is not an object (evaluating 'prevdeps.length’)»?
The error is from react-native App, that worked very fine yesterday.

The problem is occuring after console.log('here 2'), when running setContender(... ):

Here is the whole source code. This was working fine. it just suddenly started to give the «undefined is not an object (evaluating 'prevdeps.length’)» error.

note that contenders is an array of the form

````
   

     Array [
            Object {
                "createdBy": "delarosaye@gmail.com",
                "questioneeCounter": 1,
                "questioneeName": "Abrish",
                "roomCode": "32ef5d5",
                "roomName": "zara",
                "scoreCounter": 1,
                "type": 1,
                "users": Array [
                    Object {
                    "profilePic": "https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/5C51E427-1715-44E6-9B14D9487D7B7F2D_source.jpg",
                    "score": 0,
                    "userName": "Abrish",
                    `enter code here`},
                ],
            },
        ]
        
        ```
        import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
        import {View, Text, Image, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
        import styled from 'styled-components'
        import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
        import { useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native'
        import { login } from '../redux/actions'
        import _ from 'lodash'
        import { db, auth } from '../firebase'
        import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from 'react-native-vector-icons'
        
        const Header = () => {
            let [contender, setContender] = useState([])
            let [scores, setScores] = useState([])
            let [names, setNames] = useState([])
            let [indexOfMaxScore, setIndexOfMaxScore] = useState([])
            const [contenderUpdated, setContenderUpdated] = useState(false)
            const [final, setFinal] = useState(false)
            const [userName, setUserName] = useState(null)
        
            const lang = useSelector(state => state?.lang?.lang)
            const guestName = useSelector(state => state?.user?.guestName)
            const user = useSelector(state => state?.user?.user) === undefined? auth.currentUser : useSelector(state => state?.user.user)
            const profilePic = auth.currentUser?.photoURL
            const navigation = useNavigation()
            const dispatch = useDispatch()
        
            //let contender = useSelector(state => state?.contender.contenders)
            let contenders = useSelector(state => state?.contender.contenders)
            let group = contenders[0]?.type
            group = group === 2 ? true : false
        
            useEffect(() => {
                if (user || guestName) {
                    console.log('Here 0')
                    setUserName(user ? user?.userName : guestName)
                }
            }, [user, guestName])
        
            useEffect(() => {
                if (contenders?.length > 0) {
                        console.log('Here 1')
                        setContenderUpdated(true)
                    }
            }, [contenders])
        
            useEffect(() => {
                if (contenderUpdated === true) {
                    console.log('Here 2')
                    db.collection(contenders[0]?.roomName).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                        setContender(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
                    })
                    setFinal(true)
                    setContenderUpdated(false)
                }
            }, [contenderUpdated])
        
            useEffect(() => {
                if (final === true) {
                        console.log('Here 3')
                        contender = group === true ? contender?.map(item => item.users) : contender[0]?.users
        
                        scores = !group === true ? (
                            contender?.map((item) => item?.score)
                        ) : (
                            _.flatten(contender).map(item => item?.score)
                        )
                        setScores(scores)
        
                        names = !group === true ? (
                            contender?.map((item) => item?.userName)
                        ) : (
                            _.flatten(contender).map(item => item?.userName)
                        )
                        setNames(names)
                        //console.log('header', scores, names)
                
                        indexOfMaxScore = (scores?.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, scores)))
                        setIndexOfMaxScore(indexOfMaxScore)
                    }
            }, [final])
        
            const signOut = () => {
                user && (
                    auth.signOut().then(() => {           
                        //dispatch(updateContenders([]))
                        //dispatch(setQuestionees([]))
                        //dispatch(setCategoryId(0))
                        const userData = null
                        dispatch(login(userData))
                    })
                    )
                    if (contender?.length > 0) {
                        let newContender
                        if (contender[0]?.type === 2) {
                            newContender = contender?.filter(item => item.roomCode === roomInfo?.roomCode)
                            console.log('new contender', newContender)
                        }
                        
                        const newUsers = contender[0]?.type === 1 ?
                        contender[0]?.users?.filter(item => userName !== item.userName) :
                        newContender[0]?.users?.filter(item => userName !== item.userName)
                        db.collection(contender[0]?.roomName).doc(contender[0]?.roomCode).set({
                            users: newUsers
                        }, { merge: true })
                    }
                    setFinal(false)
                navigation.replace('welcome')
            }
            
            return (
                <HeaderContainer>
                    <HeaderLeft>
                        <View
                            style={{
                                width: 45,
                                height: 45,
                                backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
                                borderRadius: 999,
                                display: 'flex',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center'
                            }}
                        >
                            {profilePic ? (
                                <Image
                                    source={{ uri: profilePic }}
                                    style={{
                                        width: 40,
                                        height: 40,
                                        borderRadius: 999,
                                        resizeMode: 'stretch'
                                    }}
                                />
                                ) : (
                                    <Text style={{color: 'gray', fontSize: 25, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{user ? user?.userName?.charAt(0).toUpperCase() : guestName?.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}</Text>           
                                )}
                            </View>
                            <HeaderInfo>
                                <HeaderName>{auth.currentUser?.displayName ? auth.currentUser?.displayName : guestName}</HeaderName>
                                <HeaderEmail>{auth.currentUser?.email ? auth.currentUser?.email : 'Guest'}</HeaderEmail>
                            </HeaderInfo>
                    </HeaderLeft>
                        {contender?.length > 0 && scores[indexOfMaxScore] > 0 &&
                            <HeaderCenter>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{lang === 'en' ? 'Leader ' : 'ዉድድር ዝመርሕ ዘሎ '}
                                <Text
                                    style={{
                                        textTransform: 'capitalize',
                                        color: 'white',
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        textStyle: 'italic',
                                        }}>{names[indexOfMaxScore] + ' - ' + scores[indexOfMaxScore]} {lang === 'en' ? (scores[indexOfMaxScore] === 1 ? ' point' : 'pointes') : 'ነጥቢ'}
                                    </Text>
                                </Text>
                            </HeaderCenter>
                        }
                    <HeaderRight>
                        <HeaderSignout onPress={signOut}>
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name='logout' size={30} color='gray'/>
                        </HeaderSignout>
                    </HeaderRight>
                </HeaderContainer>
            )
        }
        
        export default Header
````

Answer (score 0):

@Abraham. I met that kind of error many times in the past.
The reason of that error is the value of the prevdeps maybe null.
I am sure that, Yesterday you had some value (not null) in that variable. :)
Please try with this. You have to make some validation to prevdeps....

```
prevdeps && prevdeps.length
```

If still gets error, call me. I will be happy to answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Lucky, I will try your suggestion, and will let you know of the outcome.

Comment: it is still not working same error message. stopping after console.log('here 2')

Comment: I fixed it. Just changed  const user = useSelector(state => state?.user?.user) === undefined? auth.currentUser : useSelector(state => state?.user.user) to const user = auth.currentUser